# How do I remove a Workflow from a List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I'm trying to remove a workflow that's been associated to a document library. Normally I would go to the library settings and then to workflow settings and remove the workflow, but on my O365 site I do not get that option because it tells be in the browser that no workflows are associated, however, SPD tells me that 3 workflows are associated to that list. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262779(v=office.14).aspx

In case the link dies here is the text:

> To remove a workflow association from a list or document library
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:
>
>    - You must be a member of the Site Owners group on the SharePoint site that you are configuring.
> 2. Browse to the list or library from which you want to remove a workflow.
> 3. Do one of the following:
>
>    - For a list, on the **List Tools** tab, click **List**.
>    - In the **Settings** group, click **List Settings**.
>    - For a library, on the **Library Tools** tab, click **Library**.
>    - In the **Settings** group, click **Library Settings**.
> 4. On the List Settings or Library Settings page, in the **Permissions and Management** section, click **Workflow Settings**.
> 5. On the Workflow Settings page, click **Remove a workflow**.
>
> **Note - The Remove a workflow link is not displayed if no workflows are associated with the list or library.**
>
> 6. On the Remove Workflows page, find the workflow that you want to remove and choose from the following options:
>
>    - Select **No New Instances** to prevent new instances of this workflow from running but still allow for running instances to finish.
>
>      After all running workflows are finished, you can return to this page to completely remove the workflow association.
>    - Select **Remove** to prevent new instances of this workflow from running and remove all instances of this workflow. This option removes
>      instances that are already running.
> 7. Click OK.

Comment: Just a note that this article is for SharePoint 2010, not SharePoint Online.