# Removing Workflow after item has been deleted

Tags: workflow

I had a list that had over 12000 items with worflows that were runnning. I have delete the list items but the workflows still appear in the workflow settings which is preventing other workflows from starting.

How do I remove them?

SharePoint 2013 Workflows

Listworkflows                      12431

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove workflow association from the list ([How do I remove a Workflow from a List?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91747/how-do-i-remove-a-workflow-from-a-list))

And delete orphan tasks and tasks of terminated workflows ([cleanup tasks from workflows and deleted items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87964/cleanup-tasks-from-workflows-and-deleted-items))